# I am getting an error about circular import even though I imported it correctly. Why?

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, tkinter, qr-code

I am trying to code how to get the qrcode from text and got this error repeatedly

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import qrcode
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def generate_qr_code():
text = text_entry.get()

if text:
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=1, error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L, box_size=10, border=4)
    qr.add_data(text)
    qr.make(fit=True)

    img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")

    # Resize the image to display it in the Tkinter window
    img = img.resize((250, 250), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

    qr_code_label.config(image=img_tk)
    qr_code_label.image = img_tk
else:
    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please enter some text.")

    # Tkinter setup
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Text to QR Code Generator")

    text_label = tk.Label(root, text="Enter text:")
    text_label.pack(pady=5)

    text_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=40)
    text_entry.pack(pady=5)

    generate_button = tk.Button(root, text="Generate QR Code", command=generate_qr_code)
    generate_button.pack(pady=10)

    qr_code_label = tk.Label(root)
    qr_code_label.pack()

    root.mainloop()

this is the code 
and this is the error
```

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'qrcode' has no attribute 'QRCode' (most likely due to a circular import). Did you mean: 'qrcode'?

Comment: Do you have an own file "qrcode.py" lying around somewehere? Or is your script called like that? Maybe you could edit your question and add the full traceback.

Comment: is it possible you named the file containing the code above as `qrcode.py`?  if so try changing the name of the file so that it doesn't clash with the `qrcode` library you are trying to import

Comment: You can use **Ctrl+ Left-Click** the `qrcode` in `import qrcode` to check the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can **Ctrl+ Left-Click** the qrcode in `import qrcode` to check the error.

At the same time, please check if there is a file with the same name `qrcode.py` in your workspace. As far as I know, [qrcode](https://pypi.org/project/qrcode/) should be a python package.

If it doesn't help, try command `pip uninstall qrcode` then `pip install qrcode`.